# Trigger for generating IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create trigger for generating ID in table:

```
    CREATE TABLE client (
    clientID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    personalID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT verifyPersonalID CHECK ((personalID BETWEEN 1000000000 and 9999999999) and (MOD(personalID, 11) = 0))
);
```

I tried to write it like this but it keeps returning errors and I dont know why. Can you, please, give me an advice what Im doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER clientID
AFTER INSERT
    ON client
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE client
    SET client.clientID = klientSeq.nextval
    WHERE :new.personalID = client.personalID;
END;
/
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: What is/are the specific error(s) you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You want a *before* insert trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER klientID
BEFORE INSERT
    ON klient
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT klientSeq.nextval INTO :new.cisloKlienta FROM dual;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of creating a trigger, you could make the default value of the primary key the next value of the sequence.

Comment: Well, we have to unfortunately use trigger.

Comment: @user6056873 It's for a class?

Comment: Yes. We have done it via .nextval, but we have been told to do it via triggers.